# Change default language in iOS app

Tags: html, ios, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a hybrid iOS app in iOS 7 and PHP/HTML/JS. I have made a webviewer and therein I loaded my web-part of the app.

I have a photo uploader like this in HTML:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

If I tap the button, iOS show me three default options:

```
 1) Take Photo
 2) Choose Existing
 3) Cancel
```

All these options are in English. Is it possible to set those to Dutch?
So, is it possible to change a sort of app language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you localize your application: http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014, and change your iPhone language settings to Dutch, (Settings->General->International->Language), then those options will be shown in Dutch.